# OS X Terminal app command result output has the input command at the beginning (zsh)

Tags: bash, macos, terminal, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I am using Terminal App on Mac OS X (10.11) and I found that every command output (except for `clear`) prepend the command I inputted at the beginning of the result. As shown in the following screenshot:
[image: Terminal command output]

Hyper has the same issue, but its working on iTerm2.

And I am using zsh (zsh 5.0.8 (x86_64-apple-darwin15.0)) with oh-my-zsh, actually, it works fine in bash.

Comment: Problem found, `TERM="screen-256color"` cause this, solution for this could be found at [stack exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/139082/zsh-set-term-screen-256color-in-tmux-but-xterm-256color-without-tmux)